# Understating the DEM and DTC flow

Tags: embedded, diagnostics, autosar

I am familiar with the key terms used in DEM and DTC concepts, but not the entire DEM flow. Could someone please give me some advice on where to start and how to understand the DEM's flow? (Setting the DTC and the how DEM continuedly monitors)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's recommended that you read through ISO14229-1 to understand the requirements for implementing UDS diagnostic protocol.

Then, take a look at the AUTOSAR Diagnostic Event Manager (DEM) module documentation, which can be found at the AUTOSAR website's development and validation methodology page (https://www.autosar.org/standards/classic-platform/development-and-validation-methodology/19-11/#documentation).

Additionally, you can refer to the open source code of DEM to gain a better understanding of its specific processes. The code can be found at the openAUTOSAR GitHub repository under the classic-platform_lib/modules/dem directory (https://github.com/openAUTOSAR/classic-platform/tree/master/autosar/classic_platform_lib/modules/dem).